# swift json string with array value convert to [UInt8]

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, swifty-json

I have a json string:

```
let msg={\"type\":\"PONG\",\"content\":[52,55,49,56,51,54,56,56,55,46,57,52,54,55,57,50]}
```

and I use following code to parse:

```
let receiveMsg = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(NSString(string: msg!).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableDictionary
```

then I could get the type by:

```
let type = receiveMsg["type"]?.stringValue
```

I want to try the same way to get the array value by:

```
let content=receiveMsg["content"] as? [UInt8]
```

but unfortunately it fails.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization ≠ SwiftyJSON

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an exception, error, warning - anything printed on console?

Answer (score 2):

The value of the key `content` is an array of `Int`.

You can convert it to `[UInt8]` with the `map` function

```
let content = receiveMsg["content"] as! [Int]
let contentUInt8 = content.map{UInt8($0)}
```

Comment: this is perfact but my array may contains negative values also...so at time of negative value it gives me error....any idea how can i solve this

Comment: The first line extracts an `Int` array from the dictionary. Just omit the second line.

Comment: but i need second line conversation as i need array of UInt8. Is there any way to convert negative int to UInt8?

Comment: It depends on if there is a relationship between the signed and unsigned values. To see the difference between signed and unsigned hex `0xFF` is 255 as `UInt8` and -1 as `Int8`.